# What is a good listserv replacement?

Tags: email

A board I'm on has about 700 - 1300 members being served from a [listserv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LISTSERV) maintained by a company one of our board members is on.  This restricts the ability of other board members to use the listserv unless they are employees of the company.

They want to move to a system where anyone can administer the list.

I'm thinking of switching to Constant Contact or Google Groups.  We want something that allows list members to manage their own contact preferences and enables anyone authorized to send emails to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) today and it seems like it will work well. It has a free version for under 1K users and under 6K emails per month. The emails show as sent from me and it gives lots of tracking statistics

Answer (score 2):

[Gaggle Mail](https://gaggle.email/) is an easy to setup/use listserv alternative.

> Gaggle Mail offers the most straightforward group email service for
>   your club, association, office, society, family and more. It’ll just
>   take you a few clicks to set up your own permanent group email
>   account, then customise how your group works and how the messages
>   look.

Basically a SaaS listserv.

Answer (score 1):

[Discuss](https://discuss.email)

It allows you (as an administrator) to create any number of lists and add any number of email address to those lists. You pay based on the number of members, but messages are unlimited. Members can update their own preferences (email, password, profile photo, etc) and snooze any particular list for a day/week/month if it becomes too noisy.

Answer (score 0):

[phpbb](http://www.phpbb.com/) might be overkill, but it would likely do all you want:

> phpBB is a free flat-forum bulletin board software solution that can be used to stay in touch with a group of people or can power your entire website. With an extensive database of user-created modifications and styles database containing hundreds of style and image packages to customise your board, you can create a very unique forum in minutes.
>
> No other bulletin board software offers a greater complement of features, while maintaining efficiency and ease of use. Best of all, phpBB is completely free. We welcome you to test it for yourself today. If you have any questions please visit our Community Forum where our staff and members of the community will be happy to assist you with anything from configuring the software to modifying the code for individual needs. Learn more about phpBB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host it yourself, I know a lot of people who like [PHPlist](http://www.phplist.com/).